# How to disable auto-folding of impex code in IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea, sap-commerce-cloud, folding, impex

I have tried everything others had to say about disabling code folding in IJ, but nothing seems to work for Impex files (hybris-specific delimited files)

I have the hybris Integration plugin installed and I think this is what is messing things up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the auto-folding's `isCollapsedByDefault` property is hard-coded to true, then configuration will not help, but you can hack.

To get rid of it, you can either:

- edit the source code (change `true` in [this line](https://github.com/AlexanderBartash/hybris-integration-intellij-idea-plugin/blob/cb063f59ac972ae8f8cfa9aa76aba0ad757b2e94/src/com/intellij/idea/plugin/hybris/impex/folding/ImpexFoldingBuilder.java#L122) into `false` will work) and build your own version of the plugin (you can edit the code and run `gradlew buildPlugin` and get a zip file in `build/distributions`)
- Edit the `META-INF/plugin.xml` of the plugin jar,  remove [these lines](https://github.com/AlexanderBartash/hybris-integration-intellij-idea-plugin/blob/6d83a2e906aeaa19f4a3eceb0909e100c8a3d5c3/resources/META-INF/lang-optional-dependencies.xml#L109-L110) and restart IntelliJ. By this you won't have to re-compile a plugin yourself
- Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>+</kbd> each time when you open an Impex file, this will expand all the foldings

Comment: Yeah I decided on the latter..but such a pain :)

Comment: Another way of hacking: edit the `META-INF/plugin.xml` of the plugin jar,  remove [these lines](https://github.com/AlexanderBartash/hybris-integration-intellij-idea-plugin/blob/6d83a2e906aeaa19f4a3eceb0909e100c8a3d5c3/resources/META-INF/lang-optional-dependencies.xml#L109-L110) and restart IntelliJ.

Comment: The thing is - why would a plugin override the default settings and do something opinionated ?? I find it incredulous that an IDE would allow this to happen. So I uninstall, unjar, edit that and then re-jar and re-install ?

Comment: No need, just open the plugin jar in your `IDESettingsLocation/config/plugins/`, edit the `plugin.xml` inside, and restart IDE